# mkdocs - How can I specify toc_depth for a single document?

Tags: tableofcontents, mkdocs

I want to change the depth of the number of headers the `table of contents` present on the TOC.

I can see toc_depth option exists as a configuration option but this is global. Is there a way to specify a single document?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You can update your templates using custom templates.
Override the `toc.html` template file item macro https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs/blob/234fb10e543af4c5dcf0ee54c1d831846303f4cb/mkdocs/themes/mkdocs/toc.html#L9 and replace:

```
{%- if item.level <= config.theme.navigation_depth %}
```

by something like:

```
{% if not page.meta.toc_depth or item.level <= page.meta.toc_depth or item.level <= config.theme.navigation_depth %}
```

and add `toc_depth` in meta header of your .md page.

```
---
description: this is the page I want TOC to only display level 2 max.
toc_depth: 2
---
```

If you use [Material for MkDocs theme](https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material) you can override the `partials/toc-item.html` file with the following:

```
{% if not page.meta.toc_depth or toc_item.level <= page.meta.toc_depth %}
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks. Used `pip show mkdocs`  to find package.   In my case toc.html is in ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mkdocs/themes/mkdocs.  Another thing is that part '{%-' looks like part of syntax. In the answer's second line of code dash is missing after %, I kept mine. As I said: Worked for me.

Comment: The dash `-` (minus sign) is just a whitespace strip insruction. It doesn't impact the condition, only the rendering on the final html. So you can put it or not, it doesn't matter. See https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#whitespace-control